# How to fix the consensus issue with SoulBound Tokens - By Nathan Rawiri - From all things blockchain brisbane

Tags: tokens, consensus

The medium account receives a {soulbound} token. The person {steve} can choose to accept the token, or deny it. The body {ERC-721} can duplicate itself and pass an identical copy through to the man. *And this man {me} thought about what to say. *